# Crop multiple subimages from a big image

Tags: image

A big image have a fixed background (i.e. blue) and multiple sub images with irregular shape.

Are there any way (either tools or programs in C or Java) to produce sub-images`

Each sub-image (although they are in irregular shapes) can be of rectangle shape, with the background color (i.e. blue) removed.

**Edit:**

1. command-line is preferred, as there are hundred of thousands such images to be splitted.
2. Linux tools will be of top preference.
3. lightweight programming is ok.

A description image:

[image]

Comment: Please always post separate images to make it easy for anyone to try to process your image in different ways. If on a Unix-like OS, you can try my ImageMagick bash shell script, multicrop2, at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php. Or with ImageMagick, you can binarize the image, then use connected components to extract the bounding boxes. Then use those to crop your original. see https://imagemagick.org/script/connected-components.php

Comment: See my post below for using my script, multicrop2.

Answer (score 1):

Using my ImageMagick bash shell script, multicrop2, (http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php) follows:

Input:

[image]

```
multicrop2 -f 25 image.jpg results.jpg
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
convert results*.jpg -bordercolor blue -border 1 -fuzz 50% -fill none -draw "matte 0,0 floodfill" -shave 1x1 results-%03d.png
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The -f argument defines the tolerance (fuzz) amount for separating the background (blue) from the regions you want to extract. Since the input is JPG, compression causes the background not to be a constant color.

The second command reads all the results from my script and then flood-fills the blue background to transparent.

Comment: Maybe add a link so folks can find your scripts.

Comment: The link is in my comment. But I will add one here as well. Thanks Mark.

Answer (score 0):

For image processing an easy way is to use [processing](http://processing.org/).
Processing is pc/mac/linux and more.
Processing is opensource.
Remember to check [librairies](http://processing.org/reference/libraries/).

Comment: Can you please enlight what is more specific about this library, how shall I proceed with this.  It's like finding needles in the sea.

Comment: Try http://code.google.com/p/blobscanner/ and http://www.v3ga.net/processing/BlobDetection/

Answer (score -1):

You want ImageMagick: [imagemagick.org](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)

Comment: Please always post code examples and images. Your post is more of a comment than an answer